# BatchDataset display images and label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a `Train` and `Validation` Batch dataset:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    label_mode = 'categorical', #it is used for multiclass classification. It is one hot encoded labels for each class
    validation_split = 0.2,     #percentage of dataset to be considered for validation
    subset = "training",        #this subset is used for training
    seed = 1337,                # seed is set so that same results are reproduced
    image_size = img_size,      # shape of input images
    batch_size = batch_size,    # This should match with model batch size
)

valid_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    label_mode ='categorical',
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "validation",      #this subset is used for validation
    seed = 1337,
    image_size = img_size,
    batch_size = batch_size,
)
```

I was trying to display 9 images to show what they looked like, which i managed, but i cant seem to be able to plot their respective label.

Here is the code:

```
class_names = train_ds.class_names


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.axis("off")
```

Which displays this:

[image]

If i try to get the labels by adding: `plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])`

I get the following error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I have tried solutions from other posts like the following `plt.title(class_names[labels[i][0]])` but without any success.

When i print the labels[i] i get one hot encoding of the labels...maybe this is why?

[image]

The result code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(labels[i], axis=None, out=None)])
    plt.axis("off")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.
    plt.axis("off")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, have you tried using argmax?

```
numpy.argmax(a, axis=None, out=None)
```

This returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

Comment: you are a genius, i added the answer in the main question... thanks agains!